# C program works (and gives correct output) but crashes anyway

Tags: c, struct, compare

> The program calculates the distances between inputted cities on
>   cartesian coordinate system and outputs the closest 2 cities.

The program compiles without an issue so it must be a logical error but crashes as soon as the distance between the last 2 cities is too big (bigger than the distance between others).

When i wrote a printf inside the if statement near the end, it only showed that the if has been accessed once which can't be since if you input 3 cities i and j should be different 6/9 combinations.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
typedef struct{
    char name[16];
int x;
int y;
}city;

double distance(city a,city b)
{
double d;
d = sqrt((b.x-a.x)*(b.x-a.x) +(b.y-a.y)*(b.y-a.y));
return d;
}

int main()
{
    int n,i,j;
    city *g;
printf("Input number of cities: ");
scanf("%d",&n);
g = (city*)malloc(n*sizeof(city));
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
printf("Input name: ");
scanf("%s",g[i].name);
printf("Input x: ");
scanf("%d",&g[i].x);
printf("Input y: ");
scanf("%d",&g[i].y);
}
int maxi,maxj;
double maxdistance;

maxdistance=distance(g[0],g[1]);
for(i=0;i<n;i++){ 
    //printf("i:%d\n",i);
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        //printf("j:%d\n",j);

{ 
        if((distance(g[i],g[j]) < maxdistance) && (i!=j))
        {
            printf("debugcheck");
maxdistance = distance(g[i],g[j]);
maxi = i;
maxj = j;
        }
}

    }

}
printf("Least distance is %lf between %s and %s",distance(g[maxi],g[maxj]),g[maxi].name,g[maxj].name);
}
```

Comment: what's the size of your city names? if > 15 then you have a problem. Try with `scanf("%15s",g[i].name);` to make input secure

Comment: btw: `for(j=0;j<n;j++)` => `for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)` it's symmetric.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thank you for the suggestions, unfortunately I've already tried changing the for loop to that exact format, it still crashes if the difference in distance between cities is big (~6) and only works on the last 2 inputted cities.

Comment: Please define "crash"! Do you ge a "core dumped", "segmentation fault" or what? User Falderol's suggestion of ending `main` with a `return(0)` statement can be important if your "crash" is just your OS reporting a non-zero return value of main!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual crash might come from the fact you forgot to initialize `maxi` and `maxj` before using them. Since the condition in the loop is not necessarily encountered, you should set them to 0 and 1 when you initialize `maxdistance`.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much!

Comment: That happens when `distance(g[0],g[1]);` is indeed the max distance.

Comment: Shouldn't maxdistance be initialized to MAX_DOUBLE or whatever the largest double is called in C?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Oooooh! That makes so much sense! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.
@Adder Yes, another solution could be to initialize `maxdistance` to DBL_MAX.